# Reference request: adelic proof of Riemann-Roch theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

I'm looking for a reference giving the adelic proof of the Riemann-Roch theorem for curves. I've been working through the first chapter of Lang's *Introduction to Algebraic and Abelian Functions*, but I'm finding the writing difficult to follow. There are a number of typos and some of the proofs are a little informal for my comfort level with the material. I've also looked at Serre's *Algebraic groups and Class Fields*, but that seems to use substantially more algebraic geometry power than Lang's book.

Does anyone know of an alternative reference to Lang that presents RR for curves via Adeles, without Serre duality, sheaves, etc.?

Comment: You might like Richard Borcherd's series https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRfbnJ2a-Bs&list=PL8yHsr3EFj53Rwr6ly1oUasJXR2Qerwgj&index=1 on RR, in which he uses adeles. The actual proof is in episode 8 and 9. All over $\mathbb C$, but...

Comment: Oops, another spelling mistake. Richard Borcherds (a Fields, but not a Field's, medalist)

Comment: Fulton's *Algebraic Topology, A First Course*.

Comment: Rosen's *Number Theory In Function Fields*, Ch. 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments: Three references that give a proof of Riemann-Roch using the adèles are:

- Fulton's *Algebraic Topology, A First Course*, Chapter 21
- Rosen's *Number Theory In Function Fields*, Chapter 6
- Richard Borcherds's video lectures on algebraic geometry, lectures [8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJS8YKY1tgA&list=PL8yHsr3EFj53Rwr6ly1oUasJXR2Qerwgj&index=8) and [9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lpmZxZXZVM&list=PL8yHsr3EFj53Rwr6ly1oUasJXR2Qerwgj&index=9).